# Blazor web asset has conflicting web root

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have randomly come across this error without making any changes to the code. I had left the project in a running and working state and returned to it a day later. When opening the project I was shown the error shown below. I have searched around and I cannot find a solution to this random error. Some stack posts have suggested various solutions all of which do not seem to apply to me here e.g. duplicate appsettings.json file. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can solve it? I have tried restarting visual studio, which did not help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The wwwroot folder in the server and client effectively merge on publish you have two files with the same name and address. Remove the icon in the servers wwwroot.